# Why in ArgoCD the user is denied access to delete?

Tags: argocd

ArgoCD: v2.3.3+07ac038

Im created user with name user and added roles in argocd-cm.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  accounts.user: apiKey,login
  accounts.bpm: apiKey,login
  accounts.tectus: apiKey,login
  admin.enabled: "true"
  policy.csv: |
    p, role:org-admin, applications, *, */*, allow
    g, user, role:org-admin
  timeout.reconciliation: 15s
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"ConfigMap","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app.kubernetes.io/instance":"argocd","app.kubernetes.io/name":"argocd-cm","app.kubernetes.io/part-of":"argocd"},"name":"argocd-cm","namespace":"argocd"}}
  creationTimestamp: "2022-05-16T08:56:13Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: argocd
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-cm
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: argocd
  name: argocd-cm
  namespace: argocd
  resourceVersion: "513585810"
  uid: 30cef27a-34d6-427f-92ba-6e89b8f2be62
```

Under this user, I log in to ArgoCD UI and try to delete POD or Deployment, but I get an error:

```
Unable to delete resource: permission denied: applications, delete, default/my-app, sub: user, iat: 2023-06-27T10:37:24Z
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: Did you make sure the ConfigMap is well applied? Have you tried using ArgoCD CLI to test the permissions?